# How do I redirect my website URL using htaccess?

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I need to display

```
www.defensionem.com
```

on my site. I tried re-directing through CPanel Redirection tool, and I redirected it.

But it has stuck in a loop.

I cleared cookies, did everything possible, so the issue lies in the server side.

I noticed the changes in the .htacess file before and after redirecting.

Here is the code.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^defensionem\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.defensionem\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/www\.defensionem\.com\/" [R=301,L]
```

Now how do I re-direct my website to

```
www.defensionem.com
```

Comment: Don't use cPanel to manage redirects - it is unbelievable bad at generating .htaccess (note: 2 c's) code and is likely to cause problems - as in the above, which will result in a redirect loop. Are you trying to redirect from the bare domain ie. `example.com` to `www.example.com` - you don't actually state this in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^defensionem.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.defensionem.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

Comment: Still keeps re directing.

Comment: @DineshGupta Try clearing your browser cache. The above directives should not result in a redirect loop. However, 301 redirects are cached by the browser - so your old (incorrect) redirects are likely to have been cached! It is a good idea to test with 302 (temporary) redirects which are not cached.

Comment: @ArunKrish The dot in the _CondPattern_ should really be escaped. The `NC` flag on the `RewriteRule` is unnecessary here.